# The front end of the radar transmits data through MIPI-CSI2, which CPU should i choose?

Tags: v4l2

all

Referring to NXP's SR processor series, consider developing a radar system where the radar front-end transmits radar data through **MIPI CSI-2**, with a maximum support of 4 lane. **SPI serves** as the slave port for radar front-end configuration.
I have several question:
Firstly, i want to find a CPU processor that meets my requirements?
Secondly, can we refer to the **linux kernel v4l2** architecture to establish a collection system?
Base on my system solution, i attempted to find several processors on the NXP's SR series first, but i found that the library function of MIPI CSI-2 are partially encapsulated in code.
I am concerned that there may be issues with developing custom drivers in the future, so i will not consider using them.
Then i found in the linux kernel that CPU models such as RK3399, I.MX and SAMSUNG exynos4412 all have MIPI CSI-2, but they are all used in cameras. I want to change the camera architecture to adapt to the radar architecture.

Comment: We are already considering the `FPGA` solution, but we still want to see the CPU solution.

Comment: Sorry, the NXP' SR is incorrect, it should be NXP S32R29X